# Rails form in one line with css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a rails form but I would like all of its input fields to appear in one line. I have no experience with css and I am relatively new to rails. My form is the following:

```
<%= form_for @need, url: shipping_company_fleet_ship_voyage_needs_path(:voyage_id => @voyage.id), :html => {:class => "needForm"} do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :quantity %>
    <%= f.number_field :quantity %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :voyage_id, :value => @voyage.id %>

    <%= f.submit "Add need" %>
<% end %>
```

I have tried various things, like requesting for class .needForm float: left or display: inline but it does not seem to affect the input fields.

Can someone point me to a direction or an online example? I read all related questions here but the answers were not very helpful for me. Do I have to use bootstrap classes to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the desired result by using bootstrap default styles for forms (check this link, I used 'form-inline' and 'input-mini': http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms)

```
<%= form_for @need, url: shipping_company_fleet_ship_voyage_needs_path(:voyage_id => @voyage.id), :html => {:class => "form-inline"} do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.number_field :quantity, :value => 1, class: 'input-mini'  %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :voyage_id, :value => @voyage.id %>
  <%= f.submit "+", class: 'btn btn-small btn-primary'  %>
<% end %>
```